# Question on integral identities: constant vanishing with uniformly bounded integral

Tags: integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus, improper-integrals

I'm studying about integral identities right now and after going through some proofs I found the following statement which it has to be an obvious result since there is no further explanation for it, but I'm having a hard time understanding it:

> Let $\;\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x,y)\;dx+Cy=Const\;\;\forall y\in
>  \mathbb R\;$ where $\;C \gt 0\;$ and assume the integral
>   $\;\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x,y)\;dx\;$ is uniformly bounded for $\;
>  y \in \mathbb R\;$, then it follows $\;C=0\;$

Why is this argument valid? It must be quite easy what I'm missing here... Any help would be valuable.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By writing the given identity as
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x,y)\;dx=\text{Constant}-Cy,\qquad y \in \mathbb{R},
$$the right hand side is not bounded for $y \in \mathbb{R}$, unless $C=0$. So if the left hand side is uniformly bounded for $y \in \mathbb{R}$, you get the result.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I thought it was something more complicated!

Comment: @kaithkolesidou You are welcome.